# Proof of shape of epithelia cells

Tags: cell-biology, tissue, bio-mechanics

In this [article](https://www.molbiolcell.org/doi/10.1091/mbc.e17-01-0060), the mentioned in the introduction that the  the optimal shape of epithelia cells in drosophila tissue is hexagonal (packing is approximately 6).

Is there an article that proves experimentally this shape? Or we just depend on mathematics and calculating the average neighbours?

Comment: Welcome to Biology StackExchange! I would suggest you add some references (or explain what you mean exactly) to your claim that _the optimal shape is hexagonal_. Firstly, there are several biophysical models for the shape of epithelia with varying levels of complexity. Secondly, the tiling is of course _not_ hexagonal, it has to deviate to account for topology and cell division.

Comment: @Domen, I did. Actually I am coming from more physics background. Anyway, you said "several biophysical models". All these models are mentioning that the cells are taking a hexagonal shape (of course before rounding in cell division process). I didn't find something experimental I can fed from.

Comment: You might be missing the second part of the statement in the article: "_The optimal cell shape on a flat surface is typically hexagonal as this **minimizes surface tension**_". Therefore, the optimality in the simplest biophysical model is defined as the minimization of surface tension. Under the additional constraint that the cells be the same size, the resulting optimal tiling is the hexagonal one (compare with honeycomb). However, experimentally, we generally see that the tiling is _not_ completely hexagonal, and thus this simple model does not adequateley describe the reality.